# Implementing AJAX functionality in Sharepoint Webpart

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am looking for a tutorial or how to for implementing a Webpart that has AJAX functionality in Sharepoint 2010.  I want to avoid using the Microsoft AJAX toolkit and use only jquery ajax functionality.

1. Is it possible to wrap everything I need to get this done in a webpart for deployment to the sharepoint website. In other words can I wrap all the needed functionality in one wsp. (I am assuming yes)
2. What is the best method to accomplish this?  I am assuming jquery.ajax calls that return json based objects.  Do I need to add ashx to the webpart project? or maybe someother type of handler?

Answer (score 0):

jquery ajax calls in SharePoint:

1. Add an application page to layouts folder in your project and add method to the .cs file or codebehind of your webpart page. and attach `[WebMethod]` tag to that method.

ex:

```
 [WebMethod]
            public static string DoSomething(string param1)
            {
              //Your code
              string data=getdata();
              var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
              return jsonSerialiser.Serialize(data);

            }
```

2. Then the jquery ajax call will be:

**retvalue** will have the data returned from ajax call.

```
var dataToSend="xyz";
var AjaxPageURL = "/_layouts/Ajax.aspx/DoSomething";//change accordingly
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: AjaxPageURL,
            async: false,
            data: "{param1:'" + dataToSend + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                retvalue = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error!');
            }
        });
```